# Should Largely AI sourced content be allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion

Serious question. I for one am disinclined to use AI for answers here, but they could generate valid responses useful to inquiring minds. Is the concern the truth or how that truth is arrived at?

I've seen an answer recently deleted that was found to largely AI generated. Would it have been deleted if the source was explicitly acknowledged?

Comment: There are two key challenges for AI generated content. 1) As noted, *source attribution* is problematic. Referencing a source is *better*, but most AI models are then clueless about where their own data comes from, and do not disclose it. So most models can give you an *answer* but not explain where it comes from.

Comment: 2) Most of the current models are better termed 'Large Language Model' (LLM), where they crunch vast quantities of text to produce useful output. They will *generate an answer*, but are unable to determine whether that answer makes logical sense or to validate its usefulness. Often for ChatGPT, where it does not know the answer it will *hallucinate* and make up an answer from plausible-sounding text, creating junk answers. There are better posts from larger SE sites that explain these problems more fully.

Comment: It has not yet been demonstrated that AI _'could generate valid responses useful to inquiring minds'_. Anyone who has experimented with online ChatGPT (or had a 'conversation' with Alexa) will know what I mean. As with Quantum Computing and Torus Plasma Fusion there are vast amounts of speculation, futuristic expectation and clickbaiting agitation, but little real progress to date.

Comment: It is difficult to address a specific answer since it has already been deleted and is unavailable to see. If you can provide any specific examples, such as a closed question, that might help provide more to discuss, but the question still stands as valid, just can't be answered so concisely.

Comment: @Nigelj, The answer I referred to in another post was quite valid and useful, the meat of which was as good as many answers on this site that do not get deleted.

Comment: @Jesse, if I may be permitted to post the content here of the deleted answer I would. Quite frankly I thought it was quite good and agreeable. The content quality is in my opinion in line with many other non deleted posts. While I could perhaps see how some might suspect it was AI generated, I don't see how in doesn't meet quality standard for responses on this site.

Comment: @Austin In line with my answer below, I think we three mods, among other things, really think that the post was a huge nothing burger. Some grammar may seem wonderful, but the ideas don't amount to much in the way of explaining Bible interpretation methods. Many people only mildly familiar with Bible research might not notice the difference in meaningful content quality, which is at least one big factors about those things.

Comment: Also, thank you for raising this question Austin, and it would be good to see more upvotes on it - in the long run this Question and its Answers could become very valuable to the site.

Comment: "I've seen an answer recently deleted that was found to largely AI generated." How was this determined, If we are talking about Vincent Wong's answer [see my recent post here](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/why-was-vincent-wongs-account-suspended) he claimed he used AI not to generate his answer but to help with his language deficiency as a non-English speaker. (also his account was suspended which seems way too harsh IMO unless he has a history as a bad actor.)

Comment: @DanFefferman, This is a response to another question and answer. Here's the thing. When you punish the AI using account you not only punish them but also the people who appreciated the content provided. With regard to the question I was referencing, I actually found the AI aided response more complete than some of the others.

Answer (score 2):

It generally seems from the SE community...

## Grammarly et al seems okay; boilerplate gets tossed

This question has been discussed by the SE community at large and at length.

Not having a specific question to look at (because it was deleted), in general: *Would it have been deleted if the source was explicitly acknowledged?* Probably in most cases because it comes back to a quality issue.

About the matter of using AI for good grammar, I don't even agree with Gmail and Grammarly suggestions, so I don't use them. So, while I can't identify with that use, such use of AI-generated assistance should have no problem. The issue with the AI tools in question is that they are not limited to grammar improvements; they actually generate content.

In general, if a user needs help with grammar, a tool like [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com) or composing in a desktop wordprocessor that makes grammar suggestions or the [After the Deadline](https://afterthedeadline.com/) tool used by WordPress would the the kind of way to go. If a user is using content-generating AI, such as ChatGPT et al, ostensibly for grammar while pure grammar resources are available, I would have questions about whether "grammar" was the actual reason or just a cover story.

Since we're not endorsing, but I mentioned [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com), here are a few others that *might* be in the acceptable neighborhood because they focus mainly on grammar and readability:

- [wordtune.com](https://wordtune.com)
- [prowritingaid.com](https://prowritingaid.com)
- [whitesmoke.com](https://www.whitesmoke.com)
- [readable.com](https://readable.com/)

These are not endorsements, and I never use any of these. But, grammar tools such as these—albeit AI-driven—are generally ***not*** the types of AI tools that mods tend to identify when dissenting on content for being AI-generated.

And again, from the discussions, the dissent seems to be centered around quality and relevance, even though lack of citation is also a secondary, major factor.

AI-generated content detectors, which usually flag the same content that triggers the flags, could include tools like these:

- [sapling.ai/ai-content-detector](https://sapling.ai/ai-content-detector)
- [copyleaks.com/ai-content-detector](https://copyleaks.com/ai-content-detector)
- [x.writefull.com/gpt-detector](https://x.writefull.com/gpt-detector)

If those tend to agree a post was AI-generated, reviewers will likely have already flagged the post as low-quality. That's my experience.

In a nutshell, AI-generated answers (using AI tools that go well beyond grammar) produce what might be best described as [boilerplate content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_text). In my experience, SE strongly frowns upon posts that happen to be boilerplate-like often because, by definition, boilerplate posts are purely made up of almost everything we do not want in posts: unrelated content and wordiness.

The fact that such content often goes uncited just comes with the package. No reputable writer wants to cite boilerplate as having come from the boilerplate stack. No honest publisher wants uncited sourced content.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has used chatgpt knows that the answers on specific questions like Greek, theology etc are baseless and invalid. It generates probabilistic answers to our needs, making up false quotes to the books. You cannot trust its results. However, the general questions about language and grammar are found in it, still never trust the examples of sentences or any examples it provides.

Perplexity.ai on the other hand is a great ai search engine which does not use probability but only presents accurate search results. I have promoted it and it is highly recommended. There's a youtube video comparing these two.

Recently a profile was found using chatgpt answers, which was clearly fake and ai. I noticed he was banned but not permanently. That account was solely made to post answers as a bot. Such bots has to be banned permanently. His answers were fake,without any source. Chatgpt can cite sources but they may well be fake. This site must not allow any cheaters and bots.

The site tour itself should provide cautionary info on and benefits of using ai, and perplexity.ai should be recommended. It will save the time and reduce cheap bad or false questions.

Comment: While you may find perplexity.ai useful, we're not going to be officially promoting another for-profit company. I don't think SE staff would even allow that.

Comment: I'd like to clarify what I understand about my colleague's above comment: If a resource can be helpful, there generally isn't a problem with users sharing the fact that the resource exists and some may find it helpful; but that is very different from a site-wide policy endorsing a research competitor to serve as a replacement to the service provided by this site, which we aren't doing. I think that is a longer version of what I understand my colleague may be attempting to express. And, I agree.

Comment: Jesse, how can search engines be competitors for SE? it's very strange coz if the site guides users to thoroughly search on duckduckgo and now some great ai engines to look for their answers, including biblehub interlinear & lexicons, many bad questions will be solved before posting. The tour site only recommends searching on this site for existing delicate questions. This is only to improve content quality, by filtering unnecessary questions which maybe solved by searching on Google, biblehub and perplexity. If the user consults proper resources before, then his que will be improved.